# is active directory only for your employees

Tags: active-directory

I've always thought of active directory as being a directory of employees, but is there any reason it cant be used as a directory of customers as well?

Comment: I suppose it can, but what's the service you're offering?

Comment: I've never considered Active Directory to be an "information directory" and I abhor it when people try to use it as such. Can it be used as an "information directory"? Sure. Do I recommend that it be used for such? No.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to, you can use Active Directory for basically anything you could use a database for.

For that matter, I once worked at a company whose product stored millions of customer network devices and their configurations in Active Directory.  For the record, this is a stupid idea, but it shows what's possible with enough creativity... and questionable design decisions.

So, sure, you could use Active Directory as a directory of customers.  The more important question is why you'd want to, and why you wouldn't use a different product that's better suited to (and even specifically designed for) tracking customer information.